# SoundPool (SDK 4.0.x) int loop, any value other than zero causes crash

Tags: loops, soundpool, crash

I wonder if anyone can help.
I'm using

Android 4.0.x development kit

Win 7  64 bit platform

using the code as supplied in
http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html

testing out SoundPool examples as supplied on the web page
and my own testing using SoundPool

I'm using Eclipse
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149

This is the problem

When you invoke

SoundPool    .play(int soundID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume, int priority, int loop, float rate)

when 'int loop' is 0 (zero) then everything is fine and the sound plays perfectly, once.

However, any other value for int loop and you get this error

Sound.Test.namespace  AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12

Sound.Test.namespace  Error creating audio track

This happens in the emulator and also on my phone Samsung galaxy Nexus

I'm playing a small audio clip, it's in ogg file format, 140K long

I've used all types of file format, wav, mp3 and It's the same with any file format 
I use, so it isn't the audio file.
I need to loop a small sound file indefinitely however, setting int loop to  -1 (or any otehr value)
causes the crash.

It's driving me mad cos I've spent a day and a half on it..

Anyone know what's going on ?

many thanks,